# How to retrieve Firebase server key from Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using messaging notification feature in a chat app on android, and everything is working fine. But I know it's not safe to keep the firebase server key in source code, as it is in low code, so I would at least like to retrieve that key from a Realtime Database value, but I don't know how to do that in this interface class.

My class that is the server key (AAAJ0Gv:AA9b...):

```
public interface NotificacaoService {

    @Headers({
            "Authorization:key=AAAJ0Gv:AA9b...",
            "Content-Type:application/json"
    })
    @POST("send")
    Call<NotificationData> saveNotification(@Body NotificationData notificationData);

}
```

Where is the key "AAAJ0Gv: AA9b ..." wanted to recover from a firebase instance.

Comment: Any reason why you need to use the REST interface for Realtime Database instead of the provided Android SDK, along with security rules to determine who can read and write the relevant part of the database here?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand anything from your question. This code from this interface was based on a tutorial I used